# Apache Camel ThreadPoolExecutor(InMemorySagaService) RequestContext Problem

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have RequestContext class. Scope is Request context and proxyTargetClass mode. I am using it also in a aspectj class in order to log.

```
I am using also Apache Camel in order to provide saga pattern by using InMemorySaga service. When the service compansate it s getting an error. By the way, i m not calling as API just examining to call in proc. 

Is there anyway to use RequestContext in a async thread in Apache Camel?
```

I have used xx.setExecutorServiceManager(new DefaultExecutorServiceManager()) with no success

```
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:481)
        at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:300)
        at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:273)
        at org.apache.camel.component.bean.AbstractBeanProcessor.process(AbstractBeanProcessor.java:198)
        at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:53)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
        at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:76)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:186)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:86)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$1.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:541)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$1.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:506)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:369)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.sendExchange(ProducerCache.java:506)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.send(ProducerCache.java:213)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:139)
        at org.apache.camel.builder.DefaultFluentProducerTemplate.send(DefaultFluentProducerTemplate.java:305)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.saga.InMemorySagaCoordinator.lambda$doFinalize$7(InMemorySagaCoordinator.java:184)
        ... 10 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributesScope.get(AbstractRequestAttributesScope.java:42)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:353)
        ... 53 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("task-executor-");
    executor.setCorePoolSize(20);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(300);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(20000);
    executor.setDaemon(true);
    executor.afterPropertiesSet();
```

Comment: Where is the context that I pass the context?